# How to enable content proposal in NatTable TextCellEditor?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface, nattable

I am currently looking for content assist feature in Nattable TextCellEditor.I have found the way to attach the ContentProposalAdapter and IContentProposalProvider by extending the Nattable TextCellEditor. but ,The selected value from the proposed list is not updating in the text control.

Snippet :

```
@Override

protected Text createEditorControl(final Composite parent, final int  Style) {
this.textControl = super.createEditorControl(parent, style);

  contentProposalAdapter =
      new ContentProposalAdapter(this.textControl, new TextContentAdapter(), contentProposalProvider, keyStroke,
          null);


  contentProposalAdapter.addContentProposalListener(new IContentProposalListener() {

    @Override
    public void proposalAccepted(IContentProposal proposal) {
    System.out.println(proposal.getContent());

    }

  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is the internal FocusListener that is triggered while selecting a value in the popup. To add the support you also need to override the internal FocusListener with a listener that doesn't fire if the content proposal popup is open.

An example would be to add a boolean flag that indicates that the popup is open and add a listener that sets the flag accordingly.

```
private boolean popupOpen = false;
...
contentProposalAdapter.addContentProposalListener(new IContentProposalListener2() {

        @Override
        public void proposalPopupClosed(ContentProposalAdapter adapter) {
            this.popupOpen = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void proposalPopupOpened(ContentProposalAdapter adapter) {
            this.popupOpen = true;
        }
});
```

And then implement and set a FocusListener in the constructor that takes care of that flag.

```
this.focusListener = new FocusAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            if (!TextCellEditor.this.popupOpen) {
                if (!commit(MoveDirectionEnum.NONE, true)) {
                    if (e.widget instanceof Control && !e.widget.isDisposed()) {
                        ((Control) e.widget).forceFocus();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!TextCellEditor.this.parent.isDisposed())
                        TextCellEditor.this.parent.forceFocus();
                }
            }
        }
};
```

In case the value should be immediately committed after it is selected, you need to add a listener that performs the commit after selection.

```
contentProposalAdapter.addContentProposalListener(new IContentProposalListener() {

        @Override
        public void proposalAccepted(IContentProposal proposal) {
            commit(MoveDirectionEnum.NONE);
        }
});
```

Unfortunately the AbstractCellEditor#InlineFocusListener is private and can therefore not be extended.

Feel free to file an enhancement ticket for NatTable to introduce the ability to easily add content proposals to a text cell editor.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=NatTable

Comment: Awesome It works !! . Thanks a lot for your quick support . I will file an enhanced ticket .

Comment: In that case it would be nice to accept my answer as the correct one.

Comment: Implementing **IContentProposalListener2()** along with **FocusListener** implementation as you mentioned is working . Another option , implementing **IContentProposalListener()** does not work.

Comment: Another option , implementing **IContentProposalListener()** does not work because the method proposalAccepted () does not receive notification when a content is selected in Proposal popup as it is working for JFace TextCellEditor.

Comment: I tested the above code in the NatTable target, which is based on Luna in its current development state. There the IContentProposalListener works fine. Which platform are you using?

Comment: I tested it with eclipse kepler version

Comment: Well, there is nothing special for a NatTable TextCellEditor regarding the IContentProposalListener, so I don't understand why it should not work there if it works for you with JFace TextCellEditor. And I do not see any bugs regarding that. Are you sure you are doing the registering of the listeners correctly?On the just created instance?

Comment: I have done the listener register as I mentioned above in snippet .I followed the way that i have done it for JFace TextCellEditor.

Comment: Sorry . It is working with IContentProposalListener() also . Thank you very much for the support .

Comment: Then it would be nice if you accept the answer as the correct one